# Getting a path of an executable file from added zip file

Tags: java, eclipse

I have added a zip file to my library folder in eclipse. I configured my build path and added the .zip as an internal jar file. However, there is a .exe which I make use of in my program. Now that I have added the file internally, how could I make that .exe file execute, or get a path to this file?

Answer (score 4):

You can't execute a file from within a zip/jar.  you will need to extract the file at runtime and put it somewhere in the filesystem and then execute it using `ProcessBuilder`/`Runtime`.  if your app has some sort of "install" folder you could put it there, or you could use the system temp drive.

Comment: Oh, then that would not serve the purpose of keep everything at one place and not using an absolute path to the .exe file. How about accessing the .exe from the lib folder directly?

Comment: @andro - it would serve the purpose of keeping everything together.  you can extract the file at _runtime_.